# multiplication in Python matrices

Tags: python

I'm trying to multiply two matrices but I'm having difficulties with my code:

```
def multiply(a,b):
    mul=[[]]
    for x in range(0,len(a)):
        for n in range(0,len(a[0])):
            mul[x][n]+=a[x][n]*b[x][n]
    mul.append(mul[x][n])
    for n in mul:
        return mul

a= [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
b= [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
multiply(a,b)
```

hypothetically, I'm trying to keep the mul variable within bounds as my for functions iterate through a and b but I'm not sure why it's not working out.

Would you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: You have to initialize `mul` as a matrix of zeros of the right size.  You can't simply add to a nonexistent index and expect that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues.  First, you need to initialize `mul` with the right dimensions, as @jasonharper pointed out.  I used a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for this.

Second, you actually need 3 loops to be able to do matrix multiplication like this.

Third, a for loop with an unconditional return will only run once, so you might as well replace the last loop with `return mul`.

Fourth, the matrices you're trying to multiply are not compatible, since they're both 4x3.  The number of columns in `a` needs to be the same as the number of rows in `b`.

Here's a working version:

```py
def multiply(a,b):
    mul= [[0] * len(b[0]) for _ in range(len(a))]
    for x in range(len(a)):
        for n in range(len(b[0])):
            for pos in range(len(a[0])):
                mul[x][n] += a[x][pos] * b[pos][n]
    return mul
```

Answer (score 1):

It's more easy work with numpy matmul function to do this. Try:

```
import numpy as np

a =np.array([[2, 2], [2, 2]])
b =np.array([[2, 2], [2, 2]])

c = np.matmul(a,b)

print(c)
```